# Customizing JQuery UI Theme

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have downloaded the Jquery UI with "Start" theme. Demo is here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

I want to change the color of datepicker background from light blue to dark blue.

How can I customize it. Please tell step by step.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ -> Gallery tab -> Select "Start" theme -> click "edit" -> make changes -> when ready click "Download theme"

You will have a URL in the theme CSS file (Look for To view and modify this theme) , when you go to this URL you could see the modified theme and you can do some more changes until you are happy with the result.

Comment: @Yasin: I customized and click download. Now in development-bundle\demos\datepicker, I open it and it is showing default gray theme

Comment: Because the demos are using the base/default theme. the customized one is in css\start\ + the images folder. Check to see which css file the demos load. It is "../../themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css". If you open the index.html in the root folder of the theme you will see your customized theme.

Answer (score 2):

Go to http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/, it a web application to customize the themes. It's very intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own themes using the jQuery UI [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).